# Make contents visible with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a sliding banner on top of my website. I am using a featurify.js (http://spreadthesource.com/sandbox/featurify/) to implement that.

The issue is that when the html page first loads, it shows every of my list-item on the page. The jquery takes effect after that and then it goes away and I see the sliding banner.

I tried to fix this by making my html div to display:none and then use show() in jquery. But that does not work for me. This is the code for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/UU5Kj

```
html:
    <div id="features">
        <ul>
            <li>Discover success </li>
            <li>Keeping pace with latest technology</li>
            <li>Employee owned</li>
            <ul>
    </div>

CSS:
    #features {
        color:#a60000;
        font-size:2.25em;
        padding:1.25em;
        display:none;
    }

JS:
    $(#features).show();
```

Also, it would be great if anyone can suggest an alternate way for me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try hiding all your list items but the first. I think the plugin will automatically make them visible with the animation.

Add this to your CSS

```
#features ul li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need the quotes

```
$('#features').show();
```

Comment: Thanks but when I tried this in the jsfiddle, its not working

Comment: @ambit, Its working and Prospector is correct. check http://jsfiddle.net/UU5Kj/4/, You have not included `jquery` in framework section

Comment: its working.. sorry am new with webdevelopment ..didnt knew about that